# Is there a way to check client in Django server without user authentication?

Tags: django

So I'm trying to build a Django application which provides each user with some contents but only limited to three times each day. For sake of convenience, I'm not thinking of creating/using any pre-existing user model or authentication.
But since I have to limit the number of contents shown to each user, I have to tell if the current request is from the same person or not. I can think of enabling this in the front-end using local storage, cookie, etc. (Neglecting security issue or others, since this is just a toy project.) But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in the back-end without using user authentication. 
Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: The basic idea would be to set a random cookie on first visit, then track how often you’ve seen that cookie value. Of course, that’s easy to circumvent for the user by deleting cookies; but there’s no other even halfway reliable solution as long as you stick to anonymous users without unique identity.

Comment: @deceze Okay so if there's no other way to do this in the back-end, which one would you recommend between using cookies vs local storage? Users deleting cookies or local storage (though is not favorable) is okay because this is just a toy project.

Answer (score -1):

Use the client's IP as identifier.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache_key = "cached_content_from_" + request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"] 
content = cache.get(cache_key)
if content:
    return content
else:
    content = <your function here>
    cache.set(cache_key, content, <your time out>)
return Response(content)
```

Comment: An IP is absolutely not unique to one person nor machine.

Comment: The author is finding a way to limit the use to get too many informations without register. I think this is a suitable way. even tow person or machine use the same IP, they can both get some example data to test. Why should the content be unique?